# How do you unzip a package with multiple files into separate directories?

Tags: zip, unzip

For example, if in my current directory I have:

```
AAA.zip
BBB.zip
CCC.zip
```

An each *.zip file has

```
123.csv
456.csv
789.csv
```

How can I unzip ALL packages into their respective directories so that I have:

```
-AAA
+--- 123.csv
+--- 456.csv
+--- 789.csv
-BBB
+--- 123.csv
+--- 456.csv
+--- 789.csv
-CCC
+--- 123.csv
+--- 456.csv
+--- 789.csv
```

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can write a DOS script  or equivalent in bash

```
For each file in the directory 

   if file has .zip extension

        get the name of that file

        make directory with the name

       copy zip file to the directory

       unzip the zip file in that directory
```

Comment: My apologies, should have posted my answer a long time ago. I followed your suggestion and it worked great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post my response as a comment to the answer given by @Abhi but I failed. Still learning about stackoverflow and about using bash! The script I used was:

```
dir=/directory/with/zip/files

for i in $(ls $dir | grep zip); do

zip_folder=$(echo $i | rev | cut -c 5- | rev)

mkdir $dir/$zip_folder

mv $dir/$i $dir/$zip_folder

cd $dir/$zip_folder

unzip $i

cd $OLDPWD

done
```

Comment: The question is specifically about zip files though. It's nice of you wanting to post your solution but people looking for a solution for `tar` files will probably not find it here. Recommending deletion since your answer does not add value (w.r.t. the posted question).

Comment: You are right. Will change this and post a solution to the actual question. (zip files)